# Is there any way to get proper Unity WebApps integration in Firefox?

Tags: unity, firefox, chromium, webapps

In Chromium, if I open, say, Facebook as a webapp, the window that appears has no url, tabs, nor bookmarks bar -- making it a web *app* rather than just a browser window.  However, if I do the same thing in Firefox, I just get a normal window with url bar, etc., which fragments my browsing experience, because then tabs open in webapp windows and whatnot. My question is: is there any way to get *proper* WebApps support in Firefox?  Especially considering Firefox is the default browser...

Thanks in advance.